# Show editor area in E4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a simple perspective without the editor area:

```
public class MainPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

@Override
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
}
}
```

Now I open an editor:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().openEditor(input, "org.acme.project");
```

In E3, this made the application show the editor area (because how else would I see the newly opened editor part). In E4 (or E3 compatibility) nothing of the sort happens.

The API to open the editor area manually is `IWorkbenchPage#setEditorAreaVisible(true)`, but it does not work for me. Maybe because the intro screen is still open when I want to open the editor? It should not matter either way.

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398674) for someting like this, but it was allegedly fixed 4 years ago, in Eclipse 4.2.

So how do I show the editor area in E4?

Comment: I don't think in e4 there is any distinction between editor or part. Please check out http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Services/article.html#implementing-editor-like-behavior

Comment: @Shashwat Doesn't really matter. I wouldn't want to open views (or parts) in an invisible part of the application either.